# how to retrieve multiple columns from two tables in C#, using SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables and need to retrieve some columns from both tables based on the common key which is ProductID. I tried the following but got an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'"

```
string selectProductStatement = 
"SELECT Products.Code, Products.Description,"+
"Products.Category, Products.Price, BookProducts.Author"+
"FROM Products"+
"INNER JOIN BookProducts ON (Products.@ProductID = BookProducts.ProductID)";

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(selectProductStatement, connection);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productID", productID);
```

the tables are:

## Products

```
  ProductID
  Code
  Description
  Category
  Price
```

## BookProducts

```
  BookID PK
  ProductID FK
  Author
```

Comment: you're missing some spaces.. after `BookProducts.Author` and after `FROM Products`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I like to use a literal string for SQL commands to get rid of all the concatination all together. Saves time and headaches!

note the @ symbol before defining the string. Also wrapping commands in a 'using' brace means you cant forget to dispose of it.

```
 string selectProductStatement = @"           SELECT 
                                              Products.Code, 
                                              Products.Description,
                                              Products.Category, 
                                              Products.Price, 
                                              BookProducts.Author
                                              FROM Products
                                              INNER JOIN BookProducts 
                                              ON (Products.@ProductID = BookProducts.ProductID) ";
            string connectionString = string.Empty;

            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectProductStatement, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productID", productID);

                    //Etc
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing spaces in your SQL:

```
string selectProductStatement = 
    "SELECT Products.Code, Products.Description,"+
    "Products.Category, Products.Price, BookProducts.Author"+
    " FROM Products"+
    " INNER JOIN BookProducts ON (Products.@ProductID = BookProducts.ProductID)";
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no space between Products and INNER. Add a space before and after FROM Products on the 3rd line of your query and you'll be fine :-)

Answer (score 2):

Reckon you just need a space between "PRODUCTS" and "INNER" there mate, i.e.

```
"FROM Products "+
"INNER JOIN BookProducts ON (Products.@ProductID = BookProducts.ProductID)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
string selectProductStatement = 
"SELECT Products.Code, Products.Description,"+
"Products.Category, Products.Price, BookProducts.Author"+
" FROM Products "+
"INNER JOIN BookProducts ON (Products.ProductID = BookProducts.ProductID) WHERE Products.ProductId = @productID";
```

Answer (score 2):

Defining the string as a string literal can help with erroneous spacing:

```
string selectProductStatement = 
 @"SELECT Products.Code, Products.Description, 
Products.Category, Products.Price,
 BookProducts.Author FROM Products 
INNER JOIN BookProducts ON (Products.@ProductID =
BookProducts.ProductID)";
```

It omits the need - and associated problems/readability of multiple string fragments

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
INNER JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name;
```

Above is the general syntax for inner join query. Just follow accordingly. :)

Comment: The question had the correct syntax there were spaces missing.